# Where in Istanbul is this dome people are standing on with views across the city?

Tags: turkey, where-on-earth, identify-this, istanbul

I'd like to enjoy the scenery where the following pictures were taken:
[image: overview1]
[image: overview2]

Comment: Sadly, the dome/roof of the Büyük Valide Han has collapsed down by people who jump/sit on it. Although it has already been forbidden to go to the top of it, almost nobody cared about that rule.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Local here.

This place is called [Büyük Valide Han](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g293974-d1763230-Reviews-Buyuk_Valide_Han-Istanbul.html). It's located in Mahmutpaşa, [Fatih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatih). Its roof has an [amazing view](https://web.archive.org/web/20170727033328/http://photographymert.com/valide-han/). A lot of people want to take a selfie or jumping photos on the roof (thanks Instagram), so this place is usually crowded.

You can see similar images if you search its name on Google Search.

[image]

Comment: **NOTE**: [On 5th May 2017, the roof of Büyük Valide Han has been closed because danger of collapsing](http://www.diken.com.tr/manzaraya-ara-buyuk-valide-hanin-catisi-cokme-nedeniyle-ziyarete-kapatildi/).

Answer (score 6):

I believe they were taken at around [41.014138, 28.968943](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/41%C2%B000'50.9%22N+28%C2%B058'08.2%22E/@41.014138,28.9683958,219m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d41.014138!4d28.968943") (if you zoom right in, you can just make out the lumps they are standing on). There is also a [photo sphere](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/41%C2%B000'50.9%22N+28%C2%B058'08.2%22E/@41.0140867,28.9689127,3a,75y,58.52h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-cQ7VayosRmM%2FV3pzTiwGqQI%2FAAAAAAAAA2o%2FJS0AL_ikj8gpJg1CWJJjDNvceg48V4KDgCLIB!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2F-cQ7VayosRmM%2FV3pzTiwGqQI%2FAAAAAAAAA2o%2FJS0AL_ikj8gpJg1CWJJjDNvceg48V4KDgCLIB%2Fw203-h100-k-no-pi0-ya219.54996-ro-0-fo100%2F!7i8704!8i4352!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d41.014138!4d28.968943) at this location with a view that seems similar. The area seems to be known as Büyük Valide Han, which if placed into Google images gives lots of similar looking photos.